# Devise Ajax login: 'sessions#create' only render 'create.js.erb' when it succeed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My goal is to implement an Ajax login solution with Devise with the minimal change of patterns. I already reached it partially, but there is one problem with the failure callback. Let me explain the scenario:

1. Display login form in a modal with `remote: true` Rails/UJS convention (OK);
2. Create a custom `sessions` controller and point Devise to it (OK);
3. Create a JS view file `create.js.erb` to respond for `sessions#create` action (PROBLEM);

The problem: My `create.js.erb` only contains an `alert("Test ok")`. When I submit the `sessions#new` form with the correct credentials the file `create.js.erb` is executed, the `alert` is shown. But with wrong credentials it doesn't, returning `401 Unauthorized` status and `create.js.erb` is ignored.

Maybe someone know a quick trick to make `create.js.erb` run when login fail. This way I don't need to create a standalone Ajax script or change entire `sessions` controller.

Thank you,

### The environment:

```
VERSIONS:
Rails 4.0.2
Devise 3.2.2
```

Custom sessions controller:

```
class Website::SessionsController < ::Devise::SessionsController
  respond_to :js # without it neither on success create.js.erb runs
  layout false   # action `new` pure html which is rendered in a modal box
end
```

sessions/create.js.erb

```
alert("Test ok");
```

Server log when login fails:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-27 09:59:47 -0300
Processing by Website::SessionsController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "user"=>{"email"=>"", "password"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Fazer login"}
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms
```

Comment: you should overwrite the devise create method and manage the situation there with proper rendering of your view, otherwise, as you can see in the default create method of devise, in case session creation is not performed, it will just redirect you without rendering create.js.  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb

Comment: +1 because I'm doing this too

Comment: @sissy thanks for the help, I will try a secure way to do what you suggest, that's apparently the best alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem occurs because of:

> warden.authenticate!(...)

It raise the exception and don't render your view after.

You should to override SessionsController#create action for your own behavior. For example like this:

```
def create
  self.resource = warden.authenticate(auth_options)
  if resource && resource.active_for_authentication?
    ...
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Perfect! Then I put a condition to check if `user_signed_in?` in `create.js.erb` to redirect to home or alert with errors if it fails. Thanks!

Comment: @EdisonMachado - did this work for you? I am trying to do this as well, but if i **logger.debug resource** after the warden line runs it returns empty... Could you share your controller code please!?!?

Comment: @JoelGrannas sorry, maybe I'm late but this is my controller: https://gist.github.com/edison/c156c3858ea6cb39486d

Answer (score 9):

When successful, the `create.js.erb` template is rendered.

When unsuccessful, for any reason,  the `new.js.erb` template is rendered.

The easiest way to deal with this, is to simply add `new.js.erb`. This involves the least amount of modification to the devise controller.

---

It may be worth noting that I had to make the following adjustments, in addition to adding `remote: true` to the form, to even get the `create.js.erb` to render.

**config/initializers/devise**:

```
# If http headers should be returned for AJAX requests. True by default.
config.http_authenticatable_on_xhr = false
```

**config/routes.rb**:

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: 'users/sessions' }
```

**controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb**:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  respond_to :html, :js

end
```

Comment: I'm using the same logic but flash messages are not being set up for js requests. any guess?