# authenticated and unauthenticated routes in rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have updated my rails 4 application to Rails 5 but I am unable to set authenticated and unauthenticated routes on rails 5.

### In rails 4:

```
unauthenticated do
   root to: "home#index", as: :unauthenticated_root
end

authenticated :user do
  root :to => "home#dashboard"
end
```

---

but how to set in for rails 5 application

Answer (score 4):

This is a great application for using route constraints. Consider the following:

```
  # routes.rb

  scope module: 'authenticated', constraints: AuthConstraint.new { |user| user.present? } do
    # Management dashboard
    root 'dashboards#index'
  end

  root 'home#index'
```

The constraint is defined in the `app/constraints/auth_constraint.rb` file and can be configured as you need it to be. For example.

```
# app/constraints/auth_constraint.rb

class AuthConstraint
  def initialize(&block)
    @block = block || ->(_) { true }
  end

  def matches?(req)
    user = current_user(req)
    user.present? && @block.call(user)
  end

  def current_user(req)
    User.find_by_id(session[:user_id])
  end
end
```

This is a flexible approach to defining route access based on any desired variable (roles, auth, etc...)

Here's a link to constraints in the Rails docs: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#specifying-constraints

Answer (score 3):

I think you finding the solution which is if `user_signed_in` then redirect to `home#dashboard` else `"home#index"`, Right? then

At first, see this solution which devise says [How To: Define a different root route for logged in out users](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Define-a-different-root-route-for-logged-in-out-users) if it not work then go to below.

---

routes.rb

```
root to: "home#index", as: :unauthenticated_root
get 'dashboard', to: "home#dashboard" #=> dashboard_path
```

On your index action use like below

```
def index
    redirect_to dashboard_path if user_signed_in?
end
```

Use this top of the controller

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]
```

it will be set need authentication for `dashboard` and other action except `index`, you can also use like this

```
before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:dashboard]
```

it will be set need authentication for only `dashboard` action.

`user_signed_in?` and `authenticate_user!` is callback method if you using devise then it exists by default, if you not using devise then I believe you have your own callback method just replace this.

**Fully Formatted After Comment**

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index]

    def index 
        redirect_to dashboard_path if user_signed_in?
    end

    def dashboard 
    end

    def other_action 
    end

    .....
end
```

After rake routes

```
unauthenticated_root GET    /                       home#index
dashboard GET               /dashboard(.:format)    home#dashboard
```

**[Update after comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48877617/authenticated-and-unauthenticated-routes-in-rails-5/48878347?noredirect=1#comment85006398_48878347)**

If you have ajax login then follow this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22689877/devise-ajax-login-sessionscreate-only-render-create-js-erb-when-it-succeed)

You should overwrite the devise create method and manage the situation there with proper rendering of your view, otherwise, as you can see in the default create method of devise, in case session creation is not performed, it will just redirect you without rendering create.js

You can overwrite devise controller inside controller folder and named `registrations_controller.rb` and looks like below

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
    # POST /resource
    def create
        super
    end
end
```

And the routes look like

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => 'registrations'}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: but when after sign in go to dashboard then session is destroyed automatically.

Comment: and its show message "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.
"

please help how can resolved this issue.

Comment: @vishalyadav I don't know what's going on, see the edited section below my answer **Fully Formatted After Comment**, I have written code fully formatted which actually tested and working my live project, I believed not an issue with this code, if not working on your hand then need to refactor the whole project where actually matter.

Comment: Thanks,
Yes, your code is working.

but when after sign in go to dashboard then session destroyed.

show in Console

  Rendered devise/sessions/create.js.erb (11674.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 15435ms (Views: 11776.6ms | ActiveRecord: 72.2ms)
Started GET "/dashboard" for ::1 at 2018-02-27 08:54:38 +0530
Processing by HomeController#dashboard as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

please give me any right suggestion to resolved this issue.
Thnaks

Comment: you should overwrite the devise create method and manage the situation there with proper rendering of your view, otherwise, as you can see in the default create method of devise, in case session creation is not performed, it will just redirect you without rendering create.js. see the answer in below **Below Section** @vishalyadav

Answer (score 0):

example to protect the split dashboard (a gem for A/B testing):

```rb
# config/routes.rb
require "split/dashboard"

class AuthConstraint
  def initialize(&block)
    @block = block
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @block.call(current_user(request))
  end

  def current_user(request)
    return if request.session[:user_id].blank?
    User.find_by(id: request.session[:user_id])
  end
end

Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope constraints: AuthConstraint.new { |user| user&.dorian? } do
    mount Split::Dashboard, at: "split"
  end
end
```